# How to pass table name and other values like datetime in MySQL with python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Here is the code where I want to create a database of every uid and and there login logout time details. and yes I made a connection with mysql successfully.

```
import mysql.connector as sq
from datetime import datetime as dt

def StudentPersonalTable(uid):
    qry="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(Login_time DATETIME,Logout_time DATETIME,Permit_time DATETIME,Pass_type VARCHAR(30),Place_of_visit VARCHAR(50))".format(uid)
    mc.execute(qry)
    print ("Table Structure Created Successfully")
def StudentEntry():
    format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    uid=input("Uid: ")
    login=dt.strptime(input("login time:"),format)
    logout=dt.strptime(input("logout time:"),format)
    permit=dt.strptime(input("Permit Time:"),format)
    passtype=input("passtype:")
    place=input("Place of visit:")
    StudentPersonalTable(uid)
    cn.commit()
    mc.execute("INSERT INTO {}(Login_time,Logout_time,Permit_time,Pass_type,Place_of_visit) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(uid,login,logout,permit,passtype,place))
    cn.commit()

for i in range(2):
    StudentEntry()
```

It gives error

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Login_time' in 'field list'

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Login_time' in 'field list'

Comment: Your table exists. but does not have that column?

Comment: It have still it gives this error.